# android imageview auto scaled without overlap other view

Tags: android, layout

I have a linear layout(**mLL**) that fit the whole screen.
Within it, there are 3 things.
That is a textview contains a mulit line string.
It is followed by a imageview. The imageview fit the remain area of screen (problem here). 
That I added a horizontal menubar (radiogroup with some image buttons) and aligned it to the bottom of linear layout(**mLL**).

The result is the radiogroup button show on top of the image.
What I hope is, the imageview fit itself to occupied the whole screen, but left sufficient space for textview and a horizontal radiogroup button.

I know I can use program code to scale the image, but I wonder if there are some attributes or correct xml layout that can intuitively create above arrangement? I mean, the arrangement of some text, followed by picture, and then a menubar is so common that should have a better way to implement it.

P.S. I tried to add the menubar before the imageview. Consequently, the imageview shows on top of menubar, i.e. menubar is partially hidden.
P.S2. The menubar need to tough the bottom of screen. So, it should be added to relative to **mLL**.

Comment: please share attempted code

Comment: Please share your xml